# PyCharm で "プロジェクトに無効なpythonインタープリターが選択されています" と表示されてしまう

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharmを使ってPythonの学習をしています。
以前からPythonが起動せず困惑していたのですが、エラー表示されていました。

```
エラー:プロジェクトに無効なpythonインタープリターが選択されていますと表示されています。
```

どのように行えば、解決できますか？

教えてください。

Comment: このヘルプ記事 [Python インタープリターを構成する](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) の内容が関連しているのでは？ どのように環境を構築してエラーが表示されているかの説明を詳細化して追記してみてください。それからこちら [pythonのエラーについて](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10255804440) とマルチポストされているようですが、何か応答があったら両方の質問記事が同等の内容になるように更新しておいてください。

Answer (score 1):

PycharmはPython自体をインストールしません。
なので、別途Pythonをインストールして、そのパスを教えてあげてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]